# Can nginx protect uri (before rewrited) by basic auth?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, authentication

I have a problem with nginx when migrating from apache.

all uris are rewrited to /index.php, and ^/admin uri should be protected by basic auth.

when with apache, I configured it as below:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

<Location ~ "^/admin">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/httpd.passwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

this is nginx configuration but it does not work:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
}   

location ~* /admin/ {
    auth_basic "admin login";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/httpd.passwd;
}
```

how can i do it in nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating apache configurations are rarely a 1:1 conversion into nginx directives.  The rewrite phase is executed before the access phase, and server-level rewrite directives are executed before location selection even happens, so the if/rewrite is run before the admin location is even considered.  I would suggest something like this:

```
server {
  # general FCP try_files
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  # capture everything starting with /admin/, don't let regex locations override
  location ^~ /admin/ {
    auth_basic "admin login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/httpd.passwd;

    # should this /index.php be /admin/index.php, or does it go through
    # the normal front controller?
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    # handle /admin/*.php requests in here so they're protected by auth_basic
    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
  }

  # handle php files
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

Comment: location ^~ /admin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/httpd.passwd;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^ /index.php break;
        }
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
}